# Definition of Semicontinuity: Confusion in Rudin's RCA

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, definition, semicontinuous-functions

Rudin's RCA defines upper and lower semicontinuity as follows:

> Let $f$ be a **real or extended-real** function on a topological space. If $$\{x: f(x) > \alpha\}$$ is open for every **real** $\alpha$, $f$ is said to be lower semicontinuous. If $$\{x: f(x) < \alpha\}$$ is open for every **real** $\alpha$, $f$ is said to be upper semicontinuous.

Clearly, the author defines upper and lower semicontinuity only for **real (or extended-real) valued functions**, and not explicitly for complex functions.

Edit: I had confused this with Q2 of Chapter 2, which was unrelated for the most part. My question now boils down to extending the definition of semicontinuity to complex functions, or more generally.

Thank you for the clarifications!

Comment: Notice that $\varphi$  (also known as modulus of continuity) is the one that is lower soemcontinuous. In fact, you may consider $f$ to be a function between metric spaces $X$,$Y$ and define $\varphi(x;\delta)=sup\{d_Y(f(s),f(t)): d_X(t, s),d_X(t, y)<\delta\}$ Treat $|u-v|$ as just distance between $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Ah okay, got it. My bad! By the way, there is no notion of upper and lower semicontinuity for complex functions then?

Comment: You did not make any mistake, I was jut binging this up to tell you that there is nothing special about $f$ taking values in $\mathbb{C}$ that makes the problem more difficult.

Comment: I just expanded on my comment to show to you that concept of modulus of continuity is in a way agnostic in whether functions take values on real, complex or any metric spaces. Sorry I change the notation. $\omega$ is the symbol that most authors use for modulus of continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is to show that there is nothing special about a function taking values in $\mathbb{C}$ that makes the problem of semicontinuity of the modulus of continuity more difficult to analyze. In fact, only distance between objects play a key role.

Let $(S,d)$ and $(S',\rho)$ be metric spaces and let $h:S\rightarrow S'$. For any point $x\in S$ and $\delta>0$, denote by $B(x;\delta)=\{y\in S: d(x,y)<\delta\}$.

- The *modulus of continuity* of $h$ on $T\subset S$ is defined as
  $$\Omega_h(T):=\sup\{\rho(h(x),h(y)):x,y\in T\}.$$
- The *modulus of continuity* of $h$ at $x$ is
  defined as
  $$\omega_h(x)=\lim_{\delta\searrow0}\Omega_h(B(x;\delta))=\inf_{\delta>0}\Omega_h(B(x;\delta))$$

**Claim:** For any $r>0$, the set $J_r=\{x\in S:\omega_h(x)\geq r\}$ is closed. Indeed, if $x\in J^c_r$, $\omega_h(x)<r$ and by definition of infimum, there is $\delta>0$ such that
$\Omega_h(B(x;\delta))<r$. Clearly  $B(x;\delta)\subset J^c_r$.

From the claim, it follows that the map $x\mapsto \omega_h(x)$ is lower semicontionous: $\{\omega_x\in S: \omega_n(x)>r\}$ is open for all $r>0$.